# multi-thread unzipping. Is it possible in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, unzip

I added unzip feature to my app and noticed that it unzips very slow. Is is possible to unzip with multuple threads? **PHONE** is Samsung S6 EDGE, that is why I think it could be faster

***Retrofit2 with @Streaming, OkHttp and UNZIP:***

```
public interface FileService {

    @Streaming
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String fileUrl);
}

mFileService.downloadFile(mScheme.getmPath()).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            new AsyncTask<ResponseBody, Long, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(final ResponseBody... responseBodies) {

                    ResponseBody body = responseBodies[0];
                    long length = body.contentLength();
                    unzip(body);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    pb.setProgress(values[0].intValue());
                    tv.setText(values[0].intValue()+"%");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
                    if(aBoolean){

                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                m.setDownloaded(true);
                                mScheme.setDownloaded(true);
                                mScheme.setmPath(mScheme.getmPath().substring(0,mScheme.getmPath().indexOf(".zip")));
                                //realm.insertOrUpdate(m);
                                //realm.insertOrUpdate(mScheme);
                            }
                        });
                        Log.d(TAG, mScheme.getmPath());
                    }
                }

                private void unzip(ResponseBody body) {

                    long fileSize = body.contentLength();
                    long fileSizeDownloaded = -1;

                    try  {
                        InputStream in = body.byteStream();
                        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);
                        ZipEntry ze = null;
                        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

                            if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                                _dirChecker(ze.getName());
                            } else {
                                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(Constants.CONFIG.CACHE_LOCATION + ze.getName());
                                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                                    publishProgress(fileSizeDownloaded * 100/fileSize);
                                    fileSizeDownloaded++;
                                    fout.write(c);
                                }

                                zin.closeEntry();
                                fout.close();
                            }

                        }
                        zin.close();
                        Log.d("Decompress", "done");
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
                    }

                }

                private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
                    File f = new File(Constants.CONFIG.CACHE_LOCATION + dir);

                    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
                        f.mkdirs();
                    }
                }
            }.execute(response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```java
for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
    publishProgress(fileSizeDownloaded * 100/fileSize);
    fileSizeDownloaded++;
    fout.write(c);
}
```

Reading a byte a time is pretty slow. This might speed up:

```java
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = zin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    publishProgress(fileSizeDownloaded * 100/fileSize);
    fileSizeDownloaded += bytesRead;
    fout.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Maybe you can parallelize processing by dispatching a separate thread for each file that needs unzipping.

Comment: You are HERO of my day))

Comment: @ЧечилКрым if it helped you, please consider accepting the answer

Comment: about "parallelize processing". Could you please point me some articles?

Comment: @ЧечилКрым oracle java tutorial for concurrency https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ or you can just dive into ExecutorService https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html there are a lot of answers about ExecutorService in SO

Comment: @ЧечилКрым by the way, parallelize the unzipping will demand a bunch of work and i don't know if it will make the process sensibly faster. If you think the unzipping time is ok now, i suggest you to leave it as it is

Comment: it satisfies the requirement to be faster. I thought about unzipping one zip file with multiple threads. What do you think about it? I tried `ThreadPoolExecutor` before, but it doesn't work properly with retrofit's `@Streaming`

Comment: @ЧечилКрым that's the difficult part... multithreading design depends a lot on the application domain, the envolved libraries, and the developer's skills. Unfortunately i don't have acquaintance with these libraries, so i can't help much more than that, sorry